# Oledb Command To Get Data From Excel Sheet Uing Where Clause 

Tags: c#, excel

Oledb Command To Get Data From Excel Sheet Uing Where Clause.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can absolutely do this:

```
select * from [Sheet1$] where [Column1] = 'whatever'
```

Comment: What part doesn't work? Are you getting an exception? Can you post a sample of the select command you're trying to execute? Then I can tailor the answer to your situation ... :)

Comment: OleDbDataAdapter dr = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + workSheetNames[i].ToString() + "] where [Column6]='5:21'", con)

Comment: Hmm, which part is not working - the selecting or the filtering? Are you getting any data? Are you getting an exception? Do the values in your worksheetNames array have dollar signs at the end of them? Is there really a column labelled "Column6"?

Comment: Another thought: is it possible that the Jet engine is interpreting your Column6 as DateTime? If so, you might need to write your query like this:

    select * from [Sheet1$] where [Column6] = #12/30/1899 5:23#